# Concavity of entropic function (information bottleneck)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, information-theory, entropy

Let $X$ and $Y$ be statistically dependent variables and let $T$ be another random variable such that the Markov condition $Y\rightarrow X\rightarrow T$ holds. For some $\beta\in [0,1]$, the information bottleneck Lagrangian (see Defintion 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.11000.pdf)) is defined as

$$\mathcal{L}_{IB}(T ; \beta)=I(T ; Y)-\beta I(X ; T)$$

$I(X:Y)$ for two finite dimensional random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint distribution $p(X,Y)$ and marginal distributions $p(X)$ and $p(Y)$ is defined as

$$I(X:Y) = \sum_{x,y} p(x, y)\log \frac{p(x, y)}{p(x)p(y)}$$

Hence, we can rewrite $\mathcal{L}_{IB}$ as purely a function of $p(t|x)$ (all others in the expression below are given)

$$\mathcal{L}_{IB}=\sum_{y, t}\left[ \left(\sum_x p(t|x)p(x|y)p(y)\right) \log \frac{\left(\sum_x p(t|x)p(x|y)p(y)\right)}{p(y)\sum_{x} p(t|x)p(x)} \right]\\ - \beta \sum_{x, t} p(t | x) p(x) \log \frac{p(t | x)}{\sum_x p(t|x)p(x)}$$

$\mathcal{L}_{IB}$ is not concave in $p(t|x)$ for all $\beta$. Indeed $\beta = 0$ is a good counterexample. Yet multiple algorithms exist that maximize it. They are guaranteed to converge to the global maximum (although convergence speed is not provably bounded). How do these algorithms guarantee not to get stuck in a local maximum?

NB: I have edited the question since the discussion in the comments was very useful.

Comment: The paper you cited gives a reference for the concavity of the functional, just a few lines after definining it. Did you read that?

Comment: I do think something is off, though - if I set $\beta = 0$, then the Lagrangian is just $I(T;Y)$, which for fixed $p_y$ is known to be *convex* in the channel $p_{t|y}$. This channel is, of course, a linear function of your decision variables $p_{t|y} = \sum_x p_{t|x}p_{x|y}$ by the Markov structure. So the functional should be convex at $\beta = 0,$ not concave...

Comment: @stochasticboy321 it gives a reference for the concavity of the IB functional (defined in (1) of the linked paper) but not the IB Lagrangian (defined in (2) of the linked paper and which I wrote in the question). Moreover, to be totally honest, the reference for concavity of the IB functional itself cites another paper from the 1970s which was quite hard to follow for me. As for your second comment, yes this was also a bit puzzling to me. Yet the IB Lagrangian is maximized by an algorithm proposed by Tishby et. al.

Comment: Why does it need to be convex if it can be optimised in practice? It's been very very long since I read the paper which defined the IB problem (I think Tishby, Bialek, and someone?), but I remember that they stated an alt min style algorithm by introducing auxiliaries for $p_t$ and something else, and gave a convergence analysis. In which case, this is an algorithm that converges eventually, but with no speed guarantees. This is similar to the situation with EM - which, iirc, is quite efficient in practice as long as the dimensions aren't too large.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I see - perhaps I should read that paper more carefully but your answer is that the Lagrangian is in fact non concave and the optimizing algorithm is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: This is not quite what I said, or at least wanted to say. There are definitely values of $\beta$ for which the Lagrangian is not concave. This doesn't mean that there are no guarantees.$$ $$
I don't have time to properly read the Tishby-Pereira-Bialek (TPB) paper, but skimming tells me the following (be warned that there may be errors in my understanding) - the form of the IB Lagrangian is quite amenable to first order analysis, which gives three equations that solutions must satisfy - one is a Gibbs-like relation, which involves a KL divergence, and the other two are consistency relations.

Comment: (contd.) TPB argue that if you iteratively solve these equations, then you converge - this is the subject of theorem 5. Note that there's no analysis of *how quickly* you converge - this is where statements like efficiently for low dimensions would come in - in practice, the method will converge quickly as long as the dimensionality is not too large, but there's no analysis guaranteeing, say, poly-time convergence or something.  (Compare to EM algorithm)$$ $$

The other thing that needs to be shown is that the solutions you get to this way give you the value (or a value close to)

Comment: (contd.) $F_{IB, \max}(r)$ (in the notation of the 2019 paper) for $r$ the value of $I(X;T)$ your stationary point takes. I think they do argue this somewhere in the TPB paper, but I'm not sure. It's possible that there's no such guarantee. This is not uncommon - AFAIK, EM doesn't have a guarantee of convergence to MLE either, it's still used. $$ $$

The 2019 paper you linked to describes three papers from the early 2000s that give algorithmic approaches. I think you should at least skim these if you're interested in what sort of guarantees these older algorithms have.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you for your clarifications - it's been very helpful and I kind of understand what to look for now. If you'd like to put what you've said as an answer, please go ahead.

Comment: you should provide more context about $I$

Comment: @LinAlg, thank you for the feedback - I have done so now!

Comment: @user1936752 you say that $I(X:Y) = \sum_{x,y} p(x)p(y|x) \log p(y|x)/p(y)$ is concave in $p(x)$ for fixed $p(y|x)$, but it is linear (and also convex), right?

Comment: @LinAlg no because the $p(y)$ in the logarithm is a function of $p(x)$ namely $p(y) = \sum_x p(x)p(y|x)$

Comment: Does $p(x)$ affect $p(y|x)$, or can we consider the latter constant?

Comment: @LinAlg $p(x)$ and $p(y|x)$ are independent variables. In the information bottleneck function, $p(t|x)$ is the variable being optimized over for fixed $p(x)$ and $p(y)$

Comment: Could you include the final expression in the question? I get $\mathcal{L}(t,\beta) = \sum_{y,t} p(y|t) p(t) \log \frac{p(y|t)p(t)}{\sum_x p(t)p(x)p(y|x)} - \beta \sum_{x,t} p(t|x) p(x) \log \frac{p(t|x)}{p(t)}$ where the variables are $p(t|x)$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @LinAlg, there are a few ways of writing it (some forms are probably easier than others). Your expression looks correct. Note that it since the mutual information is symmetric i.e. $I(X:Y) = I(Y:X)$, you can express the first term in terms of $p(t|y)$ instead of $p(y|t)$ if it helps the analysis. $p(t|y)$ can be written as a linear function of $p(t|x)$ as stochasticboy pointed out in the second comment. You may also wish to rewrite $p(t)$ in the denominator of your second term in terms of $p(t|x)$

Comment: @user1936752 what I am getting at is if you can write it as an ordinary function not involving paramters that do depend on the variables. For someone with a background in convex analysis, it is much easier to analyze normal functions :)

Comment: @LinAlg, of course, I see your point. I have added now - hopefully, it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that $I(X;T)$ is convex in $p(t|x)$ and $I(Y;T)$ is convex in $p(t|y)$. Given that $p(t|y) = \sum_x p(t|x) p(x|y)$ is a linear function of $p(t|x)$, and since a convex function of a linear function is convex, $I(Y;T)$ is also convex in $p(t|x)$. Combined, that means that $\mathcal{L}_{IB} = I(T;Y) - \beta I(T;X)$ is neither concave nor convex in $p(t|x)$.

In fact, in the general case, there are no known algorithms that are guaranteed to find the global maximum of the IB Lagrangian. The only exception to this is the case when $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Guassian (see Chechik, ‎2005).